# Events to catch when video stops playing due to another video app begins to play in multitasking mode on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, video, multitasking

Like the title says, I'm developing an iPad app which plays video in multitasking mode(using Split View or Slide Over).

When another video app begins to play(say it's Youtube), the video in my app just stops(I assume iOS won't let two apps playing the videos at the same time for whatever reasons). The Youtube app and my video app is displaying left and right side on the iPad screen at the same time(say in Split View).

My question is that what events I can catch when the video of my app stops playing so that I can, for example, display a play icon for users to resume the video when they activate my app side again in the Split View.

Note that as I observed, background-related notifications such as `UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification` or `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` won't be called, and only `rate` or `timeControlStatus`(iOS 10.0~) are called through KVO.